# Simple jquery vote count

Tags: jquery, ruby

I am developing a Rails app and need to automatically increment a very simple line bar on a voting list based on a number.

My code - I don't actually want it to increment on click, but am just providing this as reference:

```
jQuery:   
$j(".starStats div").click(function() {
 $j(this).parent().animate({
     width: '+=100px'
        }, 500);
            $j(this).prev().html(parseInt($j(this).prev().html()) + 1);
                return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<% (1..5).to_a.reverse.each do |n| %>
<tr class="starStats">
    <td><strong><%= n %> star</strong><span><%= vote.rate_summary ? vote.rate_summary[n].to_i : 0 %></span> <div>&nbsp;</div></td>
<td>(<%= vote.rate_summary ? vote.rate_summary[n].to_i : 0 %>)</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

CSS styling:

```
.starStats div {  background: #fbbf55; float: right; margin-right: 5px;width: 90px;  }
.starStats span { display: none; }
```

**[image]Example of Needed Results:**

---

5 star: xxxxxxxxxx  (296)
4 star: xxx         (28)
3 star: x           (15)
2 star: x           (16)
1 star: xxxxx       (111)

---

I just need help with the jQuery to implement the correct bar length depending on the voting number.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to have 5 different images as the bar lengths. PNG's support transparency and are cross browser compliant. It's the easier path.

Comment: ok, thanks. how would i load the correct bar length on every page load?

Comment: In your example, if you have 296 5 star votes, how wide do you want your div?

Comment: that is a really good question. The width shouldn't be any more that 90px...not sure how to make this work.  Unless the width is determined in increments?  Like 1-50 can be 10px, 51-100 is 20px, etc?

Comment: You should be able to do this without images. I don't know Ruby on Rails, but I tried my hand at it with an answer this is pure HTML, then also tried to provide the Ruby equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work:

http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/HGzqB/

I took a stab at the ruby code, since I don't know Ruby.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery:
$j( ".starStats" ).each(function()
{
    var totalVotes = parseInt( $j(".total-votes").text() ),
        votes = parseInt( $j(this).find(".votes .number").text() );
    $j( this ).find( ".percent" ).animate({
        width: '+=' + ( votes / totalVotes) * 100
    }, 500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<% (1..5).to_a.reverse.each do |n| %>
    <tr class="starStats">
        <td><strong><%= n %> star</strong></td>
        <td class="bar"><div class="percent"></div></td>
        <td class="votes">(<span class="number"><%= vote.rate_summary ? vote.rate_summary[n].to_i : 0 %></span>)</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to have 5 different images representing each different bar length.

PNG's support transparency and are cross browser compliant. It's the easier path compared to CSS.

If you're using jQuery you can modify the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag using something like:

```
<!-- You're loading a brand new page. No Reviews as of yet. -->
<img class="fivestar" src="path/to/empty.jpg" alt="no reviews yet" />


<!-- Load the appropriate CSS class to whatever object has a Five Star review -->
$(".fivestar").attr("src", "path/to/fivestarbar.png");
```